# In what forms do APIs come in, and how to write them?

Tags: api, rest

APIs are getting more and more popular and are used by developers to ease the process of developing applications to multiple platforms AND allow them to give other developers the ability to integrate their application's functionality into their own applications.

I've used APIs countless times before, but I'm now at the stage of developing my own applications. And as a developer who strives to create multi-platform applications - I need to use an API.

I'm going to use the RESTful approach as it's recommended the most.

After reading and looking for some background information, I came across: [REST API Tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com) (which is really good site!), I learned that APIs basically receive HTTP requests, and return data in JSON/XML format.

However, there were 2 questions left unanswered to me:

1. In what form do APIs come in? Are APIs actually files? a set of commands......?
2. How do I actually **write** APIs? I'm talking about the server-side, data-handling code, and not the application/language-specific code (for sending out HTTP requests etc...)

It'd be great if someone could help me and answer the questions above as I have zero experience with APIs.

Any help is appreciated - much thanks!!

Comment: apis are specifications. "send data in this format, get data back in this other format". The actual back-end implementation is irrelevant. facebook could be using an army of $0.001/day slaves to manually type in responses to everyone's page requests, and you'd never know - all you see come back out of a facebook API request is a response to your data.

Comment: But that's exactly what I want to know - how to implement the back-end so I can provide my own APIs eventually.

Comment: wrong way of looking at it. first you write an API, **THEN** you provide the backend. apis aren't written in stone, so don't worry about getting it completely right/fully implemented right away. v1. "implement hello world" v2: "implement How are You? query" v3. "implement asking how your mother is doing" etc.... the backend structure will generally flow from what you're saying the front-end is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick from-the-gut answer: They are whatever you want them to be!

Off the top of my head, I would define an API as requiring two main elements:

1. Some documentation which makes it quite clear how to use the logic your systems prvides
2. Some way to call those systems. That may be as simple as a web-site that accepts POST-messages, and checks them for certain variables and values in order to perform specific tasks.

In short, it should be entirely up to you. Just make sure you provide simple, clear and **acurate** documentation.

UPDATE, as an asnwer to the comment below:

That is how I interpret it, and it would seem that [Wikipedia is more or less in agreement with me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API#Web_APIs). PHP would be a perfect example: You could for instance create a PHP-file which processes a POST, and instead of outputting html, outputs XML with the resulting data needed. Then a third party app could POST to your PHP application, and receive and process the resulting XML.

Comment: What do you mean 'whatever I want them to be'? Can APIs simply be PHP/any language code uploaded to a server? So when I 'contact' an API, there could theoretically be some PHP file getting data from the server and returning it? (I mention PHP because this is the server-side language I'm best at...) Seems too easy if that's the case... I might as well just got the whole idea of API completely wrong if what I mentioned above turns out to be true.

Comment: Ahh there it is! There's my answer... I got API completely wrong... I thought of it as some special platform/coding language... Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Apis come as a response to a http request. It is a plain text response that u can use encoded via json or xml as you described.

There are a plenty of frameworks to help you develop and API.

In Ruby u can use [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) or [rais-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) or even [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) itself.

There is a lot more available, but this are the ones im most used to use.

Comment: Frameworks are great. But I don't wanna touch them before I know how to do it myself really... :/ Kind of kills the idea of learning... Plus I have yet to learn Ruby... Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well. to do it entirely you just need to create an application that responds to requisitions in a way the client know how to handle the response. Like a pure php application that responds data json formatted.